# QuickTime Movie View in OS 10.7 Lion

Tags: cocoa, quicktime, sigabrt

Here are the exact steps to recreate my problem:

1. New default Cocoa App project
2. Open MainMenu.xib
3. Drag a QuickTime Movie view onto the main window.
4. Try to compile.

I get a SIGABRT, why?  Is there some black magic involved with QuickTime Movie Views??

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the problem, had to add QTKit.framework to the project.  Apple boasts about how "automatic" Xcode 4 is, but wouldn't it be nice if Xcode did this automatically?